# TThread not recognized even though TTask is. (System.Threading in Uses Interface section)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, task

Delphi 10.2 FMX application for W10 x64
System.Threading in USES of the interface section.

Trying to setup a task in existing code for some comms work.
Following example online of TTask.Run followed by TThread.Synchronize to update the UI label.

On entering TTask. the autocomplete is presented as normal, select and enter...

```
//Code...

TTask.Run(procedure
begin
  Sleep(3000);
  j:=Random(50);
//------
//Note:when TThread. is entered the autocomplete is NOT presented and
//TThread is shown as an undeclared identifier.
//------
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    Label1.Text:=j.To String;
  end);
end);
```

//======
When I create a new blank application and put a button and label on the form, the above code runs ok.

If  I remove the TThread part the application compiles ok.

Both TTask and TThread are from the same unit.

Any suggestions to test?

Thanks.

Comment: TThread is declared in System.Classes.

Comment: Added Classes to the Implementation USES and it now compiles ok.

Comment: Just of curiosity, what does this mean exactly: *Threading in USES of the interface section.* (`Threading` is not a unit name)

Comment: @TomBrunberg `System.Threading` is.

Comment: While TThread and TTask both deal with threads, TThread is pretty old and trusted and has been in (System.)Classes all the time, while TTask is new and was added in a different unit, System.Threading.

Comment: @GolezTrol and Rudy, whoops! and thanks for the heads up. James, sorry for the noise.